# Is there a way to install dependencies for just one package in a yarn2 monorepo?

Tags: yarn-workspaces, yarnpkg-v2

to do a yarn immutable install for all packages it yarn 2 recommends `yarn workspaces focus --production --all`, is there a way to do this for just one workspace? reason being I would like to not have all dependencies for everything installed into docker containers for different applications.

Answer (score 6):

Yes,

`yarn workspaces focus --production` (without `--all` flag)

installs production dependencies just for the workspace in current working directory. You can also specify the name of the workspace as an argument, e.g.:

`yarn workspaces focus --production frontend`

Comment: The question and my answer are for Yarn 2, not Yarn 1